# i can't navigate to the other view in (didSelectedRowAtIndexPath)

Tags: iphone, xcode

When i click on row to navigate to the other view it give me crash

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<detailInfo 0x6b503d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lblText.'
*** First throw call stack:
"
```

This is my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    _vcontroler = [ urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!self.detailViewController)
    {
         self.detailViewController = [[[detailInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailInfo" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    }
      detailViewController.vcontroler =_vcontroler; 

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you removed an graphical object from view's frame without removing outlet connection. Select your view controller's `.xib`, then select `File's Owner` (left click on it) and remove outlet connection for `lblText` object. Build & run. It should be fine.

Comment: i remove it but still the same it make crashTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString url]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686d580'

Comment: where you receive this exception ?